# How to handle (for now) missing data?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

**Summary:** I display some data I get from an API. Due to the asynchronous nature of the calls and to various refresh  rates, I cannot assume that the `data` in my `Vue` object will be available when I call it from the HTML code. **Is there a way to handle missing data in Vue.js?**

**Details:**

The following code works (outputs `hello world`) because `message.text` is defined during the compilation of the `Vue` instance:

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#root',
  data: {
    message: {
      text: "hello"
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.3/vue.js"></script>

<div id="root">
  <span>{{message.text}}</span>
  <span>world</span>
</div>
```

If `message` is defined via an external action (a call to an API for instance) then the code below will fail:

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#root',
  data: {
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.3/vue.js"></script>

<div id="root">
  <span>{{message.text}}</span>
  <span>world</span>
</div>
```

The solution I use today is to have placeholders (default values) for the bits of `data` which will be rendered before I have a chance to update them with real values but this complexifies (and uglifies) my code when `data` gets complex.

Is there a way to instruct Vue.js to silently fail when reaching for `data` elements not defined (yet)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [v-if](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if) and not render the div until data is loaded, like following:

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#root',
  data: {
    message: {}
  },
  mounted () {
     var vm = this
     setTimeout(function(){
       vm.message = {'text' : 'Hello'}
     }, 400)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.3/vue.js"></script>

<div id="root">
  <div v-if="message.text">
    <span>{{message.text}}</span>
    <span>world</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you know the structure of the `message` data, you can initialise it  initially with empty string and dont need any `v-if` or other mechanism to prevent this error.

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#root',
  data: {
    message: {
      text: ''
    }
  },
  mounted () {
     var vm = this
     setTimeout(function(){
       vm.message.text = 'Hello'
     }, 400)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.3/vue.js"></script>

<div id="root">
  <div>
    <span>{{message.text}}</span>
    <span>world</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a good idea, but it will add a lot of "logistics" code as I have many such data (which are initialized after the initial rendering)

Comment: @WoJ If you know the structure of the message data, you can initialise it initially with empty string and dont need any "logistics" code to prevent this error. see my updated answer.

Comment: This is what I am doing today (I mentioned that at the end of my question) and wanted to avoid it as it creates a large set of data which is not useful (speaking from the perspective of the logic/readability of the code). I was hoping I could hide this somehow. I know the structure of the incoming data so it will be more or less equivalent to replicating the schema of what I am getting (with default null/empty values)

Answer (score 0):

You could just declare one variable called `asyncData` and update it when the data comes in, Vue won't throw an error if the key doesn't exist if you declare an empty object:

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    asyncData: {}
  }
});
```

Then as the data arrives you can just set it and force the Vue instance to re-render:

```
// Receive data
vm.asyncData['message'] = "Hello World!";
vm.$forceUpdate();
```

Here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tvzjsb7e/

Comment: Thank you for the idea but this will not work with the example data I gave in my question, where the data is a nested hash.

Comment: Maybe you could try doing it in a method and loop through the keys, it does depend on how complex your `data` gets, but this should work at a basic level, here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/djfjpL8v/